# Is there a way to set up a flag of some sort that can take up to four variables (used to determine if its a special move in a chess game)

Tags: python, chess

I am  writing a chess game.
I have a move class which when called runs code which works well for general moves, however I am thinking of using a optional parameter called special move for moves like castling, en passant or pawn promotion as it would require different code to be run. I am thinking of setting it to null or an empty string if it is a normal move or setting it to "castling" or "Enpassant" or "Pawnpromotion".
The move class currently looks like this:
`def __init__ (self, initalSquare, endSquare, positions):` I think I need to change it to `def __init__ (self, initalSquare, endSquare, positions, specialmove = null):` or `specialmove = ""`

The main problem with setting it to a string is it might be hard to debug if I later put a space where there isn't any or if I accidently change a capital letter or something like that. I also need to run different code when undoing/making a move if it is a special move. Another way I was thinking of doing it was setting up three flags one for each type of special move like `def __init__ (self, initalSquare, endSquare, positions, ispawnpromotion, iscastling, isenpassant):` but then I would have to  always pass them in as false which seems redundant or if they were optional parameters I would have to pass in the ones preceeding the flag I want to set to True.

Is there any better way to implement this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use an `enum`. It is a way to make a variable stay within a set of values. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) is the documentation on it, but it could look something like this:

```py
Class Special_Move(Enum):
    None = 1
    EnPassant = 2
    ...
```

You can then refer to each type as `Special_Move.EnPassant`